# how to avoid importing ZBarSDK(libzbar.a) in Xcode Everytime while opening project in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

While opening the project in Xcode, I require to import ZBarSDK(libzbar.a) & GoogleAnalytics (libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a )Everytime how to overcome this problem by importing just once.

Comment: Is it simply gone, when you reopen the project or do you get an error message?

Comment: i get error message.

Comment: And why don't you add it to your Q?

Answer (score 0):

First Delete the ZBarSDK(libzbar.a) &  GoogleAnalytics (libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a ) from your projects.

Now add (Drag)again these two file in your project. Then xcode will ask to copy or set reference in your project. Just Copy it.

then Clean and build your project. Quit xcode and reopen it.

If then also it will ask to add these files, then you have to set path of this file in your Xcode.

Step: Click on your project -> Target project ->Build setting ->now search for **Header Search Path**.
In Header Search path , you have to set the path of these two file respectively.

thank you.

Comment: its not working in my case, do you have any other suggestion...thank you